# Arrange block of table head with table data side by side in the same table using css?

Tags: html, css, html-table

### Football tournament table

I have table with multi table data which arrange under each other as you see on image under the html code, but I don't understand how to arrange (organize) table rows or table head with table date (sorry I don't know how to right say) that table data of group "A" be placed left and table date of group "B" be placed right of group "A" and same rule apply to group "D" and group "C".
I attached picture under my code for example.

Please help me to do that using only CSS, if it not difficult to explain me your solution with details.

```css
table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

table {
 width: 50%;
 border: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Table tournament</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Group <span>A</span></th>
  <th>И</th>
  <th>В</th>
  <th>Н</th>
  <th>П</th>
  <th>Голы</th>
  <th>Очки</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1.Бельгия</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>15-2</td>
  <td>22</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2.Хорватия</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>11-5</td>
  <td>17</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3.Сербия</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>13-10</td>
  <td>11</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4.Шотландия</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6-12</td>
  <td>8</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5.Македония</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6-10</td>
  <td>6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>6.Уэльс</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7-19</td>
  <td>6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Group <span>В</span></th>
  <th>И</th>
  <th>В</th>
  <th>Н</th>
  <th>П</th>
  <th>Голы</th>
  <th>Очки</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1.Италия</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>15-5</td>
  <td>20</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2.Болгария</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>13-6</td>
  <td>13</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3.Дания</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>9-10</td>
  <td>12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4.Чехия</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>8-8</td>
  <td>9</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5.Армения</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>8-10</td>
  <td>9</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>6.Мальта</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>4-18</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Group <span>С</span></th>
  <th>И</th>
  <th>В</th>
  <th>Н</th>
  <th>П</th>
  <th>Голы</th>
  <th>Очки</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1.Германия</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>28-7</td>
  <td>22</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2.Швеция</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>14-8</td>
  <td>17</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3.Австрия</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>16-8</td>
  <td>14</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4.Ирландия</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>13-13</td>
  <td>11</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5.Казахстан</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>4-17</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>6.Фарерские о.</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>3-25</td>
  <td>0</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Group <span>D</span></th>
  <th>И</th>
  <th>В</th>
  <th>Н</th>
  <th>П</th>
  <th>Голы</th>
  <th>Очки</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1.Нидерланды</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>24-4</td>
  <td>22</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2.Венгрия</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>18-12</td>
  <td>14</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3.Турция</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>14-7</td>
  <td>13</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4.Румыния</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>13-12</td>
  <td>13</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5.Эстония</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6-16</td>
  <td>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Андорра</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>0-24</td>
  <td>0</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This image demonstrates how blocks of th with td should arranges side by side.

[image: tournament football table]

Comment: https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/ZrxrBR you should nest tables. Here is some example.Every group should be in different table.And then you play a little and you are done :)

Comment: Oh, many thanks, but could  it possible to do same things in current table ( without creating additional tables)?

Comment: No, atleast every group should be in a different table.You can get rid of the outter table and use other elements (like div). Look at https://www.google.bg/search?q=world+cup+groups&rlz=1C1GCEA_enBG754BG755&oq=world+cup+groups&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6991j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sie=lg;/m/06qjc4;2;/m/030q7;st;fp;1 -> they use it like that even when they are column aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
    table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    table {
     width: 50%;
     border: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
     padding: 5px;
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <title>Table tournament</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
<tr>
<td>
     
<table>
<tr>
      <th>Group <span>A</span></th>
      <th>И</th>
      <th>В</th>
      <th>Н</th>
      <th>П</th>
      <th>Голы</th>
      <th>Очки</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1.Бельгия</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>15-2</td>
      <td>22</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>2.Хорватия</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>11-5</td>
      <td>17</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>3.Сербия</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>13-10</td>
      <td>11</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4.Шотландия</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6-12</td>
      <td>8</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>5.Македония</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6-10</td>
      <td>6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>6.Уэльс</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7-19</td>
      <td>6</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>

     <table>
           <tr>
      <th>Group <span>В</span></th>
      <th>И</th>
      <th>В</th>
      <th>Н</th>
      <th>П</th>
      <th>Голы</th>
      <th>Очки</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1.Италия</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>15-5</td>
      <td>20</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>2.Болгария</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>13-6</td>
      <td>13</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>3.Дания</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>9-10</td>
      <td>12</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4.Чехия</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>8-8</td>
      <td>9</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>5.Армения</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>8-10</td>
      <td>9</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>6.Мальта</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>4-18</td>
      <td>3</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table>    
 <tr>
      <th>Group <span>С</span></th>
      <th>И</th>
      <th>В</th>
      <th>Н</th>
      <th>П</th>
      <th>Голы</th>
      <th>Очки</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1.Германия</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>28-7</td>
      <td>22</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>2.Швеция</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>14-8</td>
      <td>17</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>3.Австрия</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>16-8</td>
      <td>14</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4.Ирландия</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>13-13</td>
      <td>11</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>5.Казахстан</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4-17</td>
      <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>6.Фарерские о.</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>3-25</td>
      <td>0</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table>
     <tr>
      <th>Group <span>D</span></th>
      <th>И</th>
      <th>В</th>
      <th>Н</th>
      <th>П</th>
      <th>Голы</th>
      <th>Очки</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1.Нидерланды</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>24-4</td>
      <td>22</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>2.Венгрия</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>18-12</td>
      <td>14</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>3.Турция</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>14-7</td>
      <td>13</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>4.Румыния</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>13-12</td>
      <td>13</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>5.Эстония</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6-16</td>
      <td>7</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Андорра</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>0-24</td>
      <td>0</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```